# Android SupportMapFragment keep increasing memory usage

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have an activity with `SupportMapFragment` inside it's `Layout`. Now I noticed that my memory grows in time while I'm on this Activity and even if I just visit this Activity and continue further.

So from 17MB of RAM usage it goes up to 50 MB in just 10 minutes.

I'm sure that this problem is related with SupportMapFragment, or Map Object, or Fragment in UI.

Any suggestions what I should try?

Answer (score 0):

This is bug filed at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766. It's marked at FixedButNotReleased, so I guess we just have to wait until the next release.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug on Google Maps Android v2 API.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766&q=apitype%3DAndroid2&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal